# Single React Component rendering with Babel Standalone with only index.html and Component

Tags: babeljs, reactjs

Noob with React here. I am playing around with React. I have a simple component to render inside my component.js. It is included in my index.html file. I included the scripts for `React`, `ReactDOM`, and `babel` in the **head**. I just want to see that one div render properly. I am not using Node yet, just a exercise with React and Babel (using [babel-standalone](http://[babel-standalone][1])). I am running the file with a simple http-server. I am getting an error with the React Chrome extension: `Waiting for roots to load...to reload inspector click here`.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- React -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <!-- React DOM -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- babel core-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.4.4/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="machine-box"></div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="components.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>`
```

**components.js**

```
class MachineBox extends React.Component {
 render(){
   return ( <div>Hello From React </div> );
 }
}

let target =  document.getElementById('machine-box');

ReactDOM.render(
 <MachineBox />, target
)
```

Comment: Add semicolons where they should be. Add one to the end of the `return` statement.

Comment: Do you get anything else in the console?

Comment: no errors in the console @loganfsmyth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine, you are using a really old version of `babel-standalone` though.

```
// this
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.4.4/babel.min.js"></script>

// should be this
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.17.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/babel" src="components.js"></script>

// should be
<script type="text/babel" src="components.js" data-presets="es2015,react"></script>
```

Comment: I have setup as above but i can not use import statement, i have to include the .js file including the component. How can i use the import and export statements? Do i have to setup webpack for that to work?

Comment: @Joseph That would be the way to do. `babel-standalone` is really only meant for the most basic testing. In any real production code you should use Webpack.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975781 for how to import modules using Babel standalone.