# React importing and rendering other component not working without tooling

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a component inside another component and then render that code into a html file. I tried everything I knew but can't get to work. I am new to React JS and want to learn it as plain as possible without any tooling and bundlers. Hence I am linking react, react-dom and babel in my html file and creating two different component js files. Can you please look at the code and guide what is wrong with it and how to fix it. I have tried export default before class Header and just export and in App.js file I tried import {Header} from './Header'; but still did not work. Thank you.

```js
/* Header Component in a Header.js file */

class Header extends React.Component 
{
    render() 
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>My Beautiful Website</h1>
                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;



/* App Component in App.js file */

import Header from './Header';

class App extends React.Component 
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
               <Header />
                <section>
                    <h2>I am trying to make this React thing work</h2>
                    <p>
                        It should be easy to do I am trying to do but may be I am a little confused about 
                        things in React JS. Sooner or later though everything gets easier and most importantly
                        crystal clear to the human mind when you persevere. I believe.
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="./App.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass [additional attribute `transform-es2015-modules-umd` to scripts if you want to use `import`,`export` and `jsx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972473/how-to-perform-import-export-in-client-side-react-jsx-using-babel-standalone/53975781)

```html
<script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" src="./Header.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd" src="./App.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

**Example**

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.14.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd">
class Header extends React.Component 
{
    render() 
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>My Beautiful Website</h1>
                <hr />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Header;
</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="transform-es2015-modules-umd">

// import Header from "./Header";
const Header = window.InlineBabelScript.default

class App extends React.Component 
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <section>
                    <h2>I am trying to make this React thing work</h2>
                    <p>
                        It should be easy to do I am trying to do but may be I am a little confused about 
                        things in React JS. Sooner or later though everything gets easier and most importantly
                        crystal clear to the human mind when you persevere. I believe.
                    </p>
                </section>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```