# Unexpected token '<' even when text/babel is used on script

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to render a button in **React** using perfectly valid **JSX** (at least, as far as I can tell after looking at it for 20 minutes). But for some reason I keep getting the syntax error:

> Unexpected token '<' on line 18

This comes as a surprise to me considering when I load the script I'm both using the `text/babel` type attribute, and the babel script is loaded in the `<head>` while this one is loaded in the DOM.

Here's what my **HTML** looks like:

```
<head>
    <!-- react, react-dom, axios etc. go here !-->
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <!-- notice that i'm using babel !-->
    <script type="text/babel" src="cdn/static/scripts/module/user.js">
</body>
```

And here is my **JavaScript**:

```
class User extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.user = props.user;
        this.state = {
            modalOpen: false
        };
    }

    Button = () => {
        let user = this.user;
        //     vvvv this is what the error points to
        return <button className={(user.loggedIn ? "user" : "sign-in")}>{(user.loggedIn ? user.public.display : "Sign In")}</button>;            
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="button">
                <this.Button />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<User user={window.User} />, document.getElementById("content"));
```

What is even stranger is that it will actually render the `button`, but because there is an error, it will also cause the rest of my **JavaScript** to break.

I've never come across this problem before so all help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Button is a function not a component, try `{this.button()}` instead of `<this.Button />` to execute the function.

Comment: @theblackgigant `<this.Button />` is an anonymous functional component and is rendered normal in all my other scripts. Should also add that changing it doesn't remove my error. :-(

Comment: try repeat simple example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972473/how-to-perform-import-export-in-client-side-react-jsx-using-babel-standalone/53975781

Comment: Don't do `this.Button()` as suggested, you must use `createElement` in order to register it to React tree.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have React scripts attached see [how to create React app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#creating-a-toolchain-from-scratch).

Because JSX is [syntatic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `React.createElement`, and custom components must be Uppercased, you should render `Button` like so:

```
class User extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super();
        this.user = props.user;
        this.state = { modalOpen: false };
    }

    Button = () => {
        let user = this.user;
        return (
            <button className={user.loggedIn ? "user" : "sign-in"}>
                {user.loggedIn ? user.public.display : "Sign In"}
            </button>
        );
    }

    render(){
        const Button = this.Button;
        return (
            <div className="button">
                <Button />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Or invoke `React.createElement` directcly:

```
<div className="button">
 {React.createElement(this.Button, null)}
</div>
```

See [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

Comment: Didn't do anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Again like I mentioned in your previous questions, do you have a reproducible example in a sandbox? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq), what does it mean "Didn't do anything", same error (not likely)? Nothing appears on the screen? [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Didn't do anything, generally, means nothing has changed. So yes, I still get the same error.

Comment: I think you don't have babel's JSX installed. https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html, https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#creating-a-toolchain-from-scratch