# How can I use ERB inside a React component? [Rails 6]

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, react-rails

I have a project on Rails 6.
Started migrating it to React by using `react-rails`. However, there are still some components which I cannot migrate to React ATM due to time limitations.

I want to be able to use the old component (`partial`) in my React component.
e.g let's say I have a React component:

Component.tsx

```
export const Component = ({post}) => {
    return <div>
      <ShareButton post={post}/>
    </div>
}
```

and somehow the ShareButton should contain this:

```
<%= render partial: 'posts/shared/share_post_btn', locals: {event: false, post: post} %>
```

I read that it may be possible by using `.jsx.erb` but I couldn't figure out how.

Would love to get some insights!
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll be mixing build pipelines here. The .erb *is* parsed by the asset pipeline, which was the default for Rails <6 and still for CSS, but this doesn't work no longer by default for yarn/webpacker-based builds that Rails 6 favoured for JS output ([Rails 7 choose a new path again](https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b), I'm sorry).

Also, as components typically have actions attached, I don't really see how a mixed Rails (static HTML) based approach could work.

A few ideas:

- In the end, both Rails/ERB and React create HTML. Perhaps you can simply create the same HTML that your ShareButton creates with Rails as a temporary workaround? You'd share the CSS from the new front-end project, and you can slowly migrate rebuilding components in React (when you're thinking of building component library, make sure it works with stand alone HTML/CSS).
- You can load static HTML in React using [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml); that might be a solution if you have complex prerendered text you want to load within a React component.
- Load React client side (relatively slow); wouldn't really do this for production: [How to perform import/export in client-side React JSX using Babel-Standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972473/how-to-perform-import-export-in-client-side-react-jsx-using-babel-standalone)
- Do some parsing of the HTML received in React; and render components conditionally (this approach is a bit how Rails Turbo works; a more Rails-native answer to React, Vue and the like)
- Push through: none of the 'solutions' above are really satisfying if you want to end up with a clean React version.
- Roll back: why use react in the first place. React is just another fancy way of rendering HTML.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I really don't like that I don't migrate all the components but some are too complex, so I'll do it one step at a time. For a particular component I did use `dangerouslysetinnerhtml` temporarily.