# How do I import an image file into a React JSX file when using Babel Standalone?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, jsx, cdn

I am developing a web app using the React CDN. In a `.js` file that defines a React component using JSX, I am trying to use the JSX `<img>` element to render an image from a local image file. Unfortunately, the image is not displaying.

In the `<body>` of my `index.html`, I have the following:

```
 <div id="coursesModeTab"></div>

...

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/coursesMode.js" type="text/babel" 
             data-plugins="transform-modules-umd" 
             data-presets="react" data-type="module">
```

Then, in `coursesMode.js`, I have the following:

```
import ssLogo from "./images/sslogo2.png";

function Logo() {
    return <img className="mode-page-icon" src={ssLogo} alt="SpeedScore logo"/>
}

const coursesDiv = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('coursesModeTab'));
coursesDiv.render(<Logo />);
```

Thanks to [this related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972473/how-to-perform-import-export-in-client-side-react-jsx-using-babel-standalone), I was able to eliminate all console errors related to not being able to use `import` statements in my `coursesMode.js` file. However, the image still does not display! Instead, I see

[image: Broken image]

when the app attempts to render the image. I can confirm that `images/sslogo2.png` exists in my project. I have also tried putting `sslogo2.png` in a `public/` directory and at the root of my project, but neither worked.

How can I make the image render properly?