# react not loading external js file

Tags: reactjs

Why does the first example work when the `jsx` script is inline but the second example not work:

UPDATE: both examples work when run off a server but only the first one works when run by just clicking on hello.html from the file system.

**First Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ReactJS Example</title>
    <script src='react/react.js'></script>
    <script src='react/react-dom.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
    </div>
    <script type='text.jsx'>             
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1> Hello, React! </h1>,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Second example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ReactJS Example</title>
    <script src='react/react.js'></script>
    <script src='react/react-dom.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
    </div>
    <script src='hello.js' type='text/jsx'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**hello.js:**

```
 ReactDOM.render(
        <h1> Hello, React! </h1>,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
```

Comment: Both work for me. Are you sure your code can find `hello.js`?

Comment: are you running it on a server or just clicking on the html file?

Comment: Running it on a server

Comment: thanks, that must be the problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in  `src`. You should correct it `src=>"hello.js"`

change

`<script src='hello'js' type='text.jsx'></script>`

to

`<script src='hello.js' type='text.jsx'></script>`

Additionally, your script type should be

`text/babel`

Maybe this will help you :

https://medium.com/@to_pe/how-to-add-react-to-a-simple-html-file-a11511c0235f

Additionally , you might want to take a lookt at this:
[Single React Component rendering with Babel Standalone with only index.html and Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230101/single-react-component-rendering-with-babel-standalone-with-only-index-html-and)
 You might have to do a few corrections.

Comment: Try using  type='text/babel'

Comment: i tried that too but it doesn't work, also your link doesn't show how to add external file

Comment: I am only trying to help here :) Is the concept that is important to get. Saying things like `just a typo`  will not help you. Nothing will work if the script is full of typos :) . I will add a few pointers, hopefully it will help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?. Are you sure the file hello.js is in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

add these scripts in your head tag. I've just solved it now

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"> 
</script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react- 
dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
```

make sure your external js script type="text/babel"